# How do I remove the first element of a tensor in keras as a layer?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

How do I remove the first element of a tensor in keras as a layer?
For example:

```
layer = Input(input_shape=(100,),name='input')
layer = Conv1D(97,kernel_size=10,strides=10)(layer)
layer = >something that removes the first element<(layer)
layer = Flaten()(layer)
model = Model(input,layer)
```

This model would have `97*9` outputs. `97` from the Conv layer, and each conv filter would output `10` nodes, but the first of those nodes would be removed by the layer I am looking for. Because the conv layer has shape `(batch_size,10,97)` I am looking for a way to remove the first element of `axis=1`.

How would I go about doing this? I tried using the Lambda layer but I can't quite figger out how to make this work.

Edit: 
 I'm asking this question because what I want to do is if I have a layer of shape `(batch_size, x, y)` I want to transform this to the shape `(batch_size, 0.5x, 2y)` in such a way that if `x` is for example `10`, the elements `0,2,4,6,8` and `1,3,5,7,9` are stacked on top of each other. Right now I'm doing this with `Maxpooling1D(pool_size=1, strides=2)` to generate `0,2,4,6,8`. To generate `1,3,5,7,9` I'd have to remove 1 element from the start in the manner explained above before applying the maxpooling layer. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: +1. I need it too, in order to implement a bi-di LSTM with offset of 2 between the left LSTM and the right LSTM

Comment: @NadavB Hey, I added an anwer just for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because @NadavB wants to know the answer:

```
layer = Input(input_shape=(100,),name='input')
layer = Conv1D(97,kernel_size=10,strides=10)(layer)
layer = Lambda(lambda x : x[:,1:,:])(layer)
layer = Flaten()(layer)
model = Model(input,layer)
```

I hope this helps you out :)

Answer (score 1):

If your only goal is to have 9 values instead of 10 out of the convolution, why don't you try this :

layer = Conv1D(97,kernel_size=11,strides=11)(layer)

? Because if you remove the first element, it means that you don't care about the 10 first values of your sequence, so you might as well feed sequences of 90 values instead of 100...
If you care about those 10 first values, and you just want to output less, then use a bigger kernel :-)

Does that help? Otherwise we can figure out a lambda layer that does the trick

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I updated my original post to clarify more why I want to use this.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a time sequence I do it this way:

```
def firstElementRemoved(inputTensor):
    return inputTensor[:, 1:]

LSTMMinusFirstElement  = Lambda(firstElementRemoved) (LSTM)
```